How to fix gap between top of foundation wall and bottom of exterior wall
I recently bought my first house. We removed some drywall in the basement for a project and saw a couple gaps between the top of our foundation wall and the exterior wall of the house. The gap in the pic below is a few inches wide and probably less than half an inch high — it is the biggest gap we have found.
The foundation wall is poured concrete, as far as I can tell. It is only about 2 feet high above the basement slab. The top of the foundation wall is only about an inch or so above the ground level outside, so the worry is that water or critters could come into the house from these gaps.
What would be the best way to fix this? Or what kind of contractor should I reach out to? Any help or advice is appreciated!
Image: https://imgur.com/a/YAq7Lai

Spray foam  for the gap. Embed hardware cloth on the outside (place it before foaming) for additional toothed pest resistance.
Consider re-landscaping to lower the ground level outside (far enough out that water goes consistently away from the building) - 1" above soil level is begging for all sorts of problems.

Kudos to you for having an answer.  To me the pic looked like a board floating in outer space..
